# Is there a quiz gem for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm looking for a simple quiz gem in Ruby on Rails.  It needs to present the user with multiple choice questions (radio buttons, checkboxes only), tally up the right/wrong answers, and display the results at the end.  The quiz will be about 25 questions - 1 question per page.  It also needs to integrate with the site I'm building, so it can't be a standalone site, or third-party site.

So far I've found this gem, which looks promising:
https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor

Anyone know of any other Quiz gems in Rails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The surveyor gem is quite powerful and I can recommend it. There is one thing that you should note: you write the survey in a dsl (ruby file with special, easy to understand syntax) and then run a rake task. This means that it's very useful for a one-off survey, where a developer can generate it (much easier and faster than doing it manually), but not if you want a non-technical person to generate surveys on her own.

Comment: Thanks, I've installed it and ran through a quiz.  The only thing I don't like is it doesn't automatically have grading built in, although you can accomplish it using a field (reference_identifier) on the answer model.  Also, there's no admin, and no results view.  But those can be custom built.  I think the model and quiz-taking is solid.

Comment: There is a field for the correct answer, I haven't used it so I don't know how well it works. Maybe worth having a look.

Comment: An update-post implementation. The gem rocks.  It's done everything we've wanted.  We had to do minor customization, but it's really easy to customize.  The results view was easy to knock out...took less than an hour.  All of the models are fully implemented, which makes writing any customizations really easy.